# How to limit Case statement when 1st condition is satisfied?

Tags: sql

I have one question. Below is a sample dataset. My query is I want to limit my data when `ic_product=competitor` then only that data should come but when `competitor` is entirely NULL then don't check the condition just display the result.

| market_code | ic_product | competitor | market_baseline | market_change | market_share | market_share | market_baseline | market_change | product_competitor_market_change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IMM19 | Tremfya | null | 0.0893 | 0.1039 | -0.0146 | null | null | null | null |
| IMM19 | Tremfya | null | 0.1624 | 0.2012 | -0.0388 | null | null | null | null |
| IMM19 | Tremfya | null | 0.218 | 0.2477 | -0.0297 | null | null | null | null |
| IMM19 | Tremfya | Tremfya | 0.0893 | 0.1039 | -0.0146 | 0.0893 | 0.1039 | -0.0146 | 0 |
| IMM19 | Tremfya | Tremfya | 0.1624 | 0.2012 | -0.0388 | 0.1624 | 0.2012 | -0.0388 | 0 |
| IMM19 | Tremfya | Tremfya | 0.218 | 0.2477 | -0.0297 | 0.218 | 0.2477 | -0.0297 | 0 |

I tried below query but it is checking both condition. Ideally should satisfy first condition and come out of loop:

```sql
SELECT * from product
WHERE 
      case when product.competitor is NOT NULL and product.competitor=product.ic_product THEN 1
      ELSE 0 END = 1
      CASE WHEN product.competitor is NULL  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1
```

I know it's not the correct way to check but my dataset can have both the scenarios: when `ic_product=competitor` then pick only those else if `competitor` is entirely NULL then don't check the condition just display the result.

Below is expected output:

When `ic_product=competitor` then below should come:

[image]

But when entire `competitor` is NULL then below is expected:

[image]

Comment: Tip 1) Use regular AND/OR instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Tip 2) You don't have to check for `product.competitor is NOT NULL` when you're also doing `product.competitor=product.ic_product`, because that comparison will be TRUE for non-null values only.

Comment: added the snap from db

Comment: If there exists at least one row (in the database table `product`) where `competitor = ic_product`, then you **only** want rows where `competitor = ic_product`. However, if all the rows in the table have `competitor is null` then you want to return all the rows. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct Abra

Comment: When you say "all rows have competitor is null", do you mean *for that product*, or do you mean *in the whole table*?

Comment: What should be returned when there isn't a row where competitor = ic_product but there is a row where competitor is not null?

Comment: Above output is a part of boarder query  through which I am getting above output, so this case won't come in where competitor != ic_product but there is a row where competitor is not null?

Comment: In other words, if `competitor` is not null then it will **always** be equal to `ic_product`, correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct

Answer (score 0):

You basically want two different result sets and you want to use a single [SQL] query that will return just one of those two result sets. I suggest a UNION of two queries where it is guaranteed that one of the queries in the UNION will not return any rows.

Note that the following is untested.

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM product
 WHERE competitor = ic_product
UNION
SELECT *
  FROM product
 WHERE competitor IS NULL
   AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                      FROM product
                     WHERE competitor = ic_product
                  )
```

If there is no row in the [database] table where `competitor = ic_product` then the first query in the UNION should not return any rows and if there is at least one row in the table where `competitor = ic_product` then the second query in the UNION should not return any rows.